# How to change font for concrete TreeListNode?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

I need to change font for TreeListNode item in XtraTreeList

For standart TreeViewNode there is Font property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout the DevExpress documentation

[XtraTreeList NodeCellStyle Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_NodeCellStyletopic)

[How to: Customize the appearance of individual cells](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5651)

```
using DevExpress.XtraTreeList;

private void treeList1_NodeCellStyle(object sender, GetCustomNodeCellStyleEventArgs e)
{
  // Modifying the appearance settings used to paint the "Budget" column's cells
  // whose values are greater than 500,000 .
  if (e.Column.FieldName != "Budget") return;
  if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Node.GetValue(e.Column.AbsoluteIndex)) > 500000)
  {
    e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 255, 0, 255);
    e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.White;
    e.Appearance.Font = new Font(e.Appearance.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use event TreeList.CustomDrawNodeCell.